# RX Subjects - are they to be avoided?

Tags: system.reactive

I've had a [mini-discussion on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9265490/58463) in another thread, and would like to have people's input on the "bad" sides of subjects.

People who frequent the RX forum know that [E.Meijer does not like Subjects](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/bbf87eea-6a17-4920-96d7-2131e397a234). While I have a deepest respect to RX creator's opinion, I have been using Subjects quite extensively in multiple projects for a couple of years and haven't had any architectural problem or a bug because of them.

The only "pitfall" with Subjects I can name is that they are not "reusable" - after you have completed an observable on a Subject, you need to re-instantiate it, before new subscribers can receive events from it.

"Code smell" and "Don't like them" need to be supported by "pragmatic" examples - can you bring to our attention possible situations when using a Subject can lead to a bug or a problem? Or maybe you think they are easy and harmless altogether - then try to define an area where they are to be used.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Erik Meijer is thinking in a purely functional way - Subjects are the mutable variables of Rx. So, in general usage he's right - using Subjects is sometimes a way to cop out of Thinking Functionally, and if you use them too much, you're trying to row upstream.

However! Subject are extremely useful when you're interfacing with the non-Functional world of .NET. Wrapping an event or callback method? Subjects are great for that. Trying to put an Rx "interface" onto some existing code? Use a Subject!

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Except that I would suggest there are already ways to wrap Events ie Observable.FromEvent(Pattern) which again is more preferable to subjects.

Comment: I believe he doesn't just mean simply wrapping the events and async calls, but using data from them. For instance, wrapping the `BeginRead`/`EndRead` pair of async calls - `EndRead` only returns the number of bytes read, to get the actual data you have to access the mutable byte array passed in to `BeginRead`.

Comment: I am actually inclined to thinking that putting a Subject upfront as a part of a public API is a terrible idea because you're exposing a vulnerable object that has dual responsibility and thus violates the principle of separation of concerns to a client, who could potentially call any of the `OnNext`, `OnCompleted`, `OnError` lambdas on it.

Comment: @PaulBetts: I am also curious as to learn what you mean by wrapping an event using a subject? Could you please provide a code snippet?

Answer (score 6):

Seems like a lot of commenters are talking past each other.

Last time I used a Subject was when I needed to pass a delegate to a middleware in an initialisation call so it could call me back when something happened. The delegate had the familiar event args signature, but I couldn't use FromEvent because there was no event.

I didn't feel bad about it - I didn't see any other choice.

Basically I used Subjects only when I'm originating some event and putting it into the Rx world, or when I need a handle to some future subscriber that hasn't arrived yet. Subjects let me link what I've got now to a later subscriber.

Comment: I infer from your comment that the `Observable.FromEvent` method did not cater to regular delegates at the time. Or may be they still don`t and they do mandate that the thing be an `event` rather than simply a delegate. I have to check that one out. But could you please post some code to show what you did? I am curious to understand the way you used `Subject<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

I use `Subject`/`Publish` whenever reactive combinators are being duplicated due to lazy eval.

However, for casual use I feel Subjects are a bit heavy - OnNext might be potential bottle neck - shows up as a hotspot during profiling, perhaps because of concurrency checks while pushing a value to subscribers.

I feel it's also cleaner for Observables you know are hot by definition.

Answer (score 1):

One reason that I would be wary of using a `Subject<T>` as a part of the public API is that it mixes concerns; an observer is a concern distinct from the observable.

What if some miscreant observer calls `OnNext` or `OnCompleted` or `OnError` on the `Subject<T>` where it was only supposed to be an *observer*?

Even if it isn't a part of the API, and you tuck it away in your server as a private backing field, just the very fact that it has a dual role is disturbing. In the case of using it as a backing field, you are still only expecting it to perform one role / concern -- that of an observable. However, it has the potential to do two things and that's just mentally disturbing.