# Replacing TaskCompletionSource with Observable

Tags: c#, system.reactive, taskcompletionsource

In my .NET 4.0 library I have a piece of code that sends data over the network and waits for a response. In order to not block the calling code the method returns a `Task<T>` that completes when the response is received so that the code can call the method like this:

```
// Send the 'message' to the given 'endpoint' and then wait for the response
Task<IResult> task = sender.SendMessageAndWaitForResponse(endpoint, message);
task.ContinueWith(
    t => 
    {
        // Do something with t.Result ...
    });
```

The underlying code uses a [TaskCompletionSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so that it can wait for the response message without having to spin up a thread only to have it sit there idling until the response comes in:

```
private readonly Dictionary<int, TaskCompletionSource<IResult>> m_TaskSources
    = new Dictionary<int, TaskCompletionSource<IResult>>();

public Task<IResult> SendMessageAndWaitForResponse(int endpoint, object message)
{
    var source = new TaskCompletionSource<IResult>(TaskCreationOptions.None);
    m_TaskSources.Add(endpoint, source);

    // Send the message here ...

    return source.Task;
}
```

When the response is received it is processed like this:

```
public void CompleteWaitForResponseResponse(int endpoint, IResult value)
{
    if (m_TaskSources.ContainsKey(endpoint))
    {
        var source = m_TaskSources[endpoint];
        source.SetResult(value);
        m_TaskSources.Remove(endpoint);
    }
}
```

Now I want to add a time-out so that the calling code won't wait indefinitely for the response. However on .NET 4.0 that is [somewhat messy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18760624/539846) because there is no easy way to time-out a task. So I was wondering if Rx would be able to do this easier. So I came up with the following:

```
private readonly Dictionary<int, Subject<IResult>> m_SubjectSources
    = new Dictionary<int, Subject<IResult>>();

private Task<IResult> SendMessageAndWaitForResponse(int endpoint, object message, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    var source = new Subject<IResult>();
    m_SubjectSources.Add(endpoint, source);

    // Send the message here ...

    return source.Timeout(timeout).ToTask();
}

public void CompleteWaitForResponseResponse(int endpoint, IResult value)
{
    if (m_SubjectSources.ContainsKey(endpoint))
    {
        var source = m_SubjectSources[endpoint];
        source.OnNext(value);
        source.OnCompleted();
        m_SubjectSources.Remove(endpoint);
    }
}
```

This all seems to work without issue, however I've seen several questions stating that `Subject` should be [avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299813/rx-subjects-are-they-to-be-avoided) so now I'm wondering if there is a more Rx-y way to achieve my goal.

Comment: Are you developing with VS2010? Otherwise, you still can target .NET 4.0 and use [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async), it has `TaskEx.Delay`, `CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter` etc.

Comment: Nope I'm on VS2012. Thanks for the pointer to the BCL library. I didn't know about that one.

Comment: No worries, you may also want to read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advice to avoid using `Subject` in Rx is often overstated. There has to be a source for events in Rx, and it's fine for it to be a `Subject`.

The issue with Subject is generally when it is used in between two Rx queries that could otherwise be joined, or where there is already a well-defined conversion to `IObservable<T>` (such as `Observable.FromEventXXX` or `Observable.FromAsyncXXX` etc.

If you want, you can do away with the `Dictionary` and multiple `Subject`s with the approach below. This uses a single subject and returns a filtered query to the client.

It's not "better" *per se*, Whether this makes sense will depend on the specifics of your scenario, but it saves spawning lots of subjects, and gives you a nice option for monitoring all results in a single stream. If you were dispatching results serially (say from a message queue) this could make sense.

```
// you only need to synchronize if you are receiving results in parallel
private readonly ISubject<Tuple<int,IResult>, Tuple<int,IResult>> results =
    Subject.Synchronize(new Subject<Tuple<int,IResult>>());

private Task<IResult> SendMessageAndWaitForResponse(
    int endpoint, object message, TimeSpan timeout)
{           
    // your message processing here, I'm just echoing a second later
    Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).ContinueWith(t => {
        CompleteWaitForResponseResponse(endpoint, new Result { Value = message }); 
    });

    return results.Where(r => r.Item1 == endpoint)
                  .Select(r => r.Item2)
                  .Take(1)
                  .Timeout(timeout)
                  .ToTask();
}

public void CompleteWaitForResponseResponse(int endpoint, IResult value)
{
    results.OnNext(Tuple.Create(endpoint,value));
}
```

Where I defined a class for results like this:

```
public class Result : IResult
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IResult
{
    object Value { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT - In response to additional questions in the comments.

- No need to dispose of the single Subject - it won't leak and will be garbage collected when it goes out of scope.
- `ToTask` does accept a cancellation token - but that's really for cancellation from the client side.
- If the remote side disconnects, you can send an the error to all clients with `results.OnError(exception);` - you'll want to instantiate a new subject instance at the same time.

Something like:

```
private void OnRemoteError(Exception e)
{
    results.OnError(e);        
}
```

This will manifest as a faulted task to all clients in the expected manner.

It's pretty thread safe too because clients subscribing to a subject that has previously sent `OnError` will get an error back immediately - it's dead from that point. Then when ready you can reinitialise with:

```
private void OnInitialiseConnection()
{
    // ... your connection logic

    // reinitialise the subject...
    results = Subject.Synchronize(new Subject<Tuple<int,IResult>>());
}
```

For individual client errors, you could consider:

- Extending your `IResult` interface to include errors as data
- You can then optionally project this to a fault for just that client by extending the Rx query in `SendMessageAndWaitForResponse`. For example, and an Exception and HasError property to IResult so that you can do something like:

  ```
  return results.Where(r => r.Item1 == endpoint)
              .SelectMany(r => r.Item2.HasError
                  ? Observable.Throw<IResult>(r.Item2.Exception)
                  : Observable.Return(r.Item2))
              .Take(1)
              .Timeout(timeout)
              .ToTask();
  ```

Comment: The point is, `Task.Delay` is not available in .NET 4.0. That's why I asked about `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`. Even if that's not an option, it's still trivial to implement via `System.Threading.Timer`, so I wonder what's holding @Petrik on.

Comment: `Task.Delay` is not part of the implementation!!! That's just a hack to simulate a response. Once you are in `IObservable<T>`, options open up that aren't available with Task. Whether you need/want them is another question. The OP was asking specifically about Subjects in Rx.

Comment: @Noseratio I could certainly use `System.Threading.Timer` or an equivalent, however that adds complexity on top of what I need and I don't trust my own skills too much with all this threading / synchronization. It seems better to use Rx or TPL where other people have solved some of those problems for me :)

Comment: @JamesWorld Thanks for that solution, it is a lot cleaner than my approach. Two (somewhat related) questions I have are how do I deal with the cancellation of the task, e.g. if the remote side disconnects I want to cancel all the outstanding tasks for that side. Currently I have a `CancellationToken` that I use for that but I'm not sure how to fit that into your approach. Secondly do I have to dispose of anything or is that done when the task completes? I'm assuming I have to eventually dispose of the main ISubject instance?

Comment: Added some more thoughts on individual client errors.