# Alternative to using Subject in reactive programming?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Use of the `Subject` type is often frowned upon in reactive programming. In the following situation, I use a `Subject` to allow subscribing to notifications before the underlying source of the notification is created. Is there an alternative to accomplish this without using `Subject`?

```
using System;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var socket = new ObservableMessageWebSocket();

        socket.Messages.Subscribe(Print); // Caller is allowed to subscribe before connect

        var uri = new Uri("ws://mydomain.com/messages");
        socket.ConnectAsync(uri).Wait(); // Caller is allowed to connect after subscribe

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Print(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}

class ObservableMessageWebSocket
{
    // Is there a way to get rid of this Subject?
    private readonly Subject<string> subject = new Subject<string>();

    private MessageWebSocket webSocket;

    public IObservable<string> Messages => subject;

    public async Task ConnectAsync(Uri uri)
    {
        webSocket = new MessageWebSocket();

        webSocket.Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Utf8;

        Observable
            .FromEventPattern<MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs>(webSocket, nameof(webSocket.MessageReceived))
            .Select(ReadString)
            .Subscribe(subject);

        await webSocket.ConnectAsync(uri);
    }

    private static string ReadString(EventPattern<MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs> pattern)
    {
        using (var reader = pattern.EventArgs.GetDataReader())
        {
            reader.UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;

            return reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
        }
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: To clarify, I have several software components that subscribe to `ObservableMessageWebSocket.Messages` for push notifications. Some components subscribe before `ObservableMessageWebSocket.ConnectAsync` is called, and some subscribe after.

The code below avoids `Subject`, but does not function correctly. A component subscribes after connect, and never receives notifications.

```
class ObservableMessageWebSocket
{
    private MessageWebSocket WebSocket { get; }

    public IObservable<string> Messages { get; }

    public ObservableMessageWebSocket()
    {
        WebSocket = new MessageWebSocket();
        WebSocket.Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Utf8;
        Messages = Observable
            .FromEventPattern<MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs>(WebSocket, nameof(WebSocket.MessageReceived))
            .Select(ReadString);
    }

    private static string ReadString(EventPattern<MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs> pattern)
    {
        using (var reader = pattern.EventArgs.GetDataReader())
        {
            reader.UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;

            return reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
        }
    }

    public async Task ConnectAsync(Uri uri)
    {
        await WebSocket.ConnectAsync(uri);
    }
}
```

The code below does not work either. Same symptom.

```
class ObservableMessageWebSocket
{
    private MessageWebSocket WebSocket { get; }

    public IObservable<string> Messages { get; }

    public ObservableMessageWebSocket()
    {
        WebSocket = new MessageWebSocket();
        WebSocket.Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Utf8;
        Messages = Observable.Create<string>(o => Observable
            .FromEventPattern<MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs>(WebSocket, nameof(WebSocket.MessageReceived))
            .Select(ReadString)
            .Subscribe(o));
    }

    private static string ReadString(EventPattern<MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs> pattern)
    {
        using (var reader = pattern.EventArgs.GetDataReader())
        {
            reader.UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;

            return reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
        }
    }

    public async Task ConnectAsync(Uri uri)
    {
        await WebSocket.ConnectAsync(uri);
    }
}
```

Somehow, the code below works.

```
class ObservableMessageWebSocket
{
    private MessageWebSocket WebSocket { get; }

    private event EventHandler<string> StringReceived;

    public IObservable<string> Messages { get; }

    public ObservableMessageWebSocket()
    {
        WebSocket = new MessageWebSocket();
        WebSocket.Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Utf8;
        WebSocket.MessageReceived += HandleEvent;
        Messages = Observable
            .FromEventPattern<string>(this, nameof(StringReceived))
            .Select(p => p.EventArgs);
    }

    private void HandleEvent(MessageWebSocket sender, MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        var handler = StringReceived;
        if (handler == null) return;
        string message;
        using (var reader = args.GetDataReader())
        {
            reader.UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
            message= reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
        }
        handler.Invoke(this, message);
    }

    public async Task ConnectAsync(Uri uri)
    {
        await WebSocket.ConnectAsync(uri);
    }
}
```

To me, all three seem similar. How come only the last one works?

Comment: With the updated code are you sure that you're actually subscribing to the observable in your test code? Also, try the `Observable.FromEventPattern<XxxEventHandler, XxxEventArgs>(h => xxx.Event += h, h => xxx.Event -= h)` syntax for observing the event.

Comment: Great suggestion. After switching to your suggested syntax, I get an exception when `WebSocket.MessageReceived += h` is called. Apparently `Observable.FromEventPattern<T>(Object, string)` swallows exceptions.

Comment: I guess the lesson learned is to always avoid `Observable.FromEventPattern<T>(Object, string)` and use something like `FromEventPattern<T>(Action<EventHandler<T>>, Action<EventHandler<T>>)` instead? The exception swallowing behavior wasted me quite a bit of time to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I don't know if it swallows exceptions - It's just not statically typed and easy to get wrong. I always use `FromEventPattern<T>(Action<EventHandler<T>>, Action<EventHandler<T>>)` for the reason that it is statically checked.

Comment: I will be following the same practice going forward. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's usually a good idea to avoid subjects. In your code you're exposing the subject directly to the calling code. Any consumer that does `((Subject<string>)socket.Messages).OnCompleted();` will stop your code working.

You're also newing up a `WebSocket` which should be disposed of afterwards.

There is a way to get ride of the subject and make it all behave a lot better.

Try this:

```
public IObservable<string> Connect(Uri uri)
{
    return
        Observable
            .Using(
                () =>
                {
                    var webSocket = new MessageWebSocket();
                    webSocket.Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Utf8;
                    return webSocket;
                },
                webSocket =>
                    Observable
                        .FromAsync(() => webSocket.ConnectAsync(uri))
                        .SelectMany(u =>
                            Observable
                                .FromEventPattern<MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs>(webSocket, nameof(webSocket.MessageReceived))
                                .SelectMany(pattern =>
                                    Observable
                                        .Using(
                                            () =>
                                            {
                                                var reader = pattern.EventArgs.GetDataReader();
                                                reader.UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8;
                                                return reader;
                                            },
                                            reader => Observable.Return(reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength))))));

}
```

---

Here's how to avoid the subject with your existing code style:

```
public IObservable<string> ConnectAsync(Uri uri)
{
    return
        Observable
            .Create<string>(async o =>
            {
                var webSocket = new MessageWebSocket();

                webSocket.Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Utf8;

                var subscription = Observable
                    .FromEventPattern<MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs>(webSocket, nameof(webSocket.MessageReceived))
                    .Select(ReadString)
                    .Subscribe(o);

                await webSocket.ConnectAsync(uri);

                return subscription;
            });
}
```

---

Here's a quick test that this works:

```
void Main()
{
    Connect(new Uri("https://stackoverflow.com/")).Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Substring(0, 24)));
}

public IObservable<string> Connect(Uri uri)
{
    return
        Observable
            .Create<string>(async o =>
            {
                var webClient = new WebClient();

                webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

                var subscription =
                    Observable
                        .Using(
                            () => new CompositeDisposable(webClient, Disposable.Create(() => Console.WriteLine("Disposed!"))),
                            _ =>
                                Observable
                                    .FromEventPattern<DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(
                                        h => webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += h, h => webClient.DownloadStringCompleted -= h)
                                    .Take(1))
                    .Select(x => x.EventArgs.Result)
                    .Subscribe(o);

                await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);

                return subscription;
            });
}
```

Note that `"Disposed!"` is displayed showing that the `WebClient` is disposed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your comment about `IDisposable` is right; In production code I do have disposal implemented, but on StackOverflow I removed those lines to emphasize the main point of my question, which is about how to allow subscribing to notifications before the underlying source of the notification is created.

Comment: @hwaien - If you want to "allow subscribing to notifications before the underlying source of the notification is created" then you should use `Observable.Create` - that's what it's there for. It then avoids the `Subject<string>`. I'll try to add that to my answer later.

Comment: @hwaien - I've added an answer to my code that is more aligned with what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I did not know about `Observable.Create`. However, after putting it to use, I find that it does not give me the results I expect. I've updated my question to include my attempt to use `Observable.Create`.

Comment: @hwaien - I think there might be something else going on now. Can you read my comment on your question?

Comment: Marking this as answer since it gives a solution to the original question of how to get rid of `Subject`.

Answer (score 1):

Subjects aren't universally bad, and I don't think there's anything terribly wrong with the way you used it. I would refer to [Why are Subjects not recommended in .NET Reactive Extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396449/why-are-subjects-not-recommended-in-net-reactive-extensions?rq=1) and [RX Subjects - are they to be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299813/rx-subjects-are-they-to-be-avoided?rq=1) for some reasonable discussion about them and their use.

Given that, I would suggest the following (while removing all of the fields and exposed properties):

```
public async Task<IObservable<string>> ConnectAsync(Uri uri)
{
    webSocket = new MessageWebSocket();

    webSocket.Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Utf8;

    var toReturn = Observable
        .FromEventPattern<MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs>(webSocket, nameof(webSocket.MessageReceived))
        .Select(ReadString);

    await webSocket.ConnectAsync(uri);
    return toReturn;
}
```

This way if someone calls `ConnectAsync` twice, they can get separate observables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The linked discussions are insightful. And your comment about multiple calls to `ConnectAsync` is right; In production code I do have logic to handle multiple calls, but on StackOverflow I removed those lines to emphasize the main point of my question.

Comment: Just a quick one, @Shlomo. The return type on this function is `Task<IObservable<string>>`, but your code appears to be returning a `Task<IDisposable>`. Am I reading that wrong?

Comment: Nope, you read right, I wrote wrong. Edited and corrected. Thank you.